# Are there hooks I can use to log file downloads

Tags: ee2, module, hook

I'm working on a module to log some statistics on downloads from anywhere in the site. My module setup is fine, it installs and creates the necessary tables. Now I want to hook into the events, file downloads in particular and log this data to my new tables.

Are there any hooks exposed that I can use to see when this happens? It crossed my mind to try and intercept the event with javascript and log it asynchronously. But I am hoping there is a hook I can use instead. I haven't been able to find one though.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't any hook for it. You might see this question/answer [Track logged-in user events](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13058/track-logged-in-user-events/13069)
which seems much similar to your need.